# Build-in kernel can't see device name

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I can't register device(there're nothing new in /dev) , even took simplest example to take a test after i flashed kernel successfully.But I can register device by using insmod .ko. yes i do

So I think there're must be some steps i feked up.
oooops, or some codes(not exist in my life) need to be insereted into driver.c
manually.

Any suggests will be appreciated !
Much obliged for your help!

[flash kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z3vD.png)

[build-in kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL5Vz.png)

Comment: So you built an external Linux kernel module called "hello", but you actually want it to be built in to the kernel? That will require the source of the "hello" driver to be patched in to the kernel source along with the appropriate modifications to `Kconfig` and `Kbuild/Makefile` files to allow it to be selected during kernel configuration and built during kernel build.

Comment: @lan Abbott     Thanks for you reply. i thought * means it  build in kernel and i  add codes like obj-$(CONFIG_HELLO_MODULE) += hello_module.o    to makefile& Kconfig ,and i  put it  /drivers/char

Comment: Yes, if that `[*] support for HELLO CONFIG_HELLO` screenshot is from a modified kernel's configuration menu then it does set the appropriate `CONFIG_` option to `y` in the kernel's `.config` file. I didn't know if your screenshot was from the kernel's configuration menu or a similar configuration menu as used by several embedded Linux build systems.

Comment: @lan Abbott    I should've cloesd this question :> . B/C I can find (i.e.  kernel/drivers/char/leds.ko)  when i use "cat modules.builtin" command, but just like i said before,  new kernel did not run some codes like  printk(DEVICE_NAME"\tinitialized\n");  in static int __init led_dev_init(void) function.

Comment: @lan Abbott     thanks 4 your help anyhow anywhen anyway   anymoment . Love ya